# Me aparece "Process terminated with status -1073741510" y no ejecuta ningún programa

Tags: c++, codeblocks

He estado ejecutando programas con normalidad hasta que en un momento simplemente empezó a mandarme este  mensaje:

```
Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minute(s), 11 second(s))
```

Con cualquier programa (inclusive con los que antes sí funcionaban).Intente reinstalar el codebloks, esta vez el de las terminaciones "mingw",pero ni aun así logro que se arregle. También intente ver si era problema de mi anti-virus, pero no encontré ningún archivo en cuarentena. Como agregado, Codeblocks siempre me pide que si deseo guardar la plantilla default antes de cerrarlo, cosa que antes no pasaba. Cabe recalcar que Codeblocks me habia funcionado bien por meses. Ya no sé que hacer  :(.

Os dejo todo el build log, por si os ayuda:

```
-------------- Run: Release in Ejercicio9 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Checking for existence: C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\2020 Diego\proyectos\Ejercicio9\bin\Release\Ejercicio9.exe
Set variable: PATH=.;C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLSClient;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\PROGRAMACIòN full\Software\Visual Basic\Microsoft VS Code\bin
Executing: "C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks/cb_console_runner.exe" "C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\2020 Diego\proyectos\Ejercicio9\bin\Release\Ejercicio9.exe"  (in C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\2020 Diego\proyectos\Ejercicio9\.)
Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minute(s), 11 second(s))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias cosas que puedes cambiar en tu entorno de trabajo para tratar de resolver este problema

1. No compiles en C:/Program Files. Si instalas en un directorio diferente (C:/CodeBlocks), donde no haya rutas con espacios, es más predecible el comportamiento. Igual con la ruta donde estén tus programas (evitar los `2020 Diego`). He visto tantos casos que tenían problema con eso, que elijo ir a lo seguro y evitarlo.
2. Reemplaza glut32 por freeglut. En [este hilo](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=20062.0) de la comunidad de C::B indican que es plausible que usar una compilación más actualizada de glut ayude a que funcione todo. No sabemos que actualización de windows te dañó todo o hizo imposible que glut32 siguiera funcionando como antes. El OP allá tenía tu mismo error y se resolvió con eso.